# Migrating key.id lists in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, migration

I am migrating an app to the High-Replication datastore. The way I understand that works is that I simply copy my data to a new app that has the HRDS enabled, using the *Datastore Admin*.

However, my app has some entities that link to other entities by means of their key.ids.

```
posts = db.ListProperty(int)
```

When I migrate the app, the ID's of objects are likely to change, no? How do I ensure that these lists still link properly?

Comment: Don't use the copy tool, use the dedicated migration tool which you can find in the Application Settings page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the datastore migration tool (as Daniel suggests), existing entity IDs will be preserved.

You really should be using lists of keys rather than IDs, though.

Comment: In this case, though, if I had used a `StringList` of keys; these keys *would* have changed because the AppID is part of the key, right? Or does the migration tool take that into account too? Why is it better to use keys; is it to take into account multiple apps/namespacing?

Comment: @Noio If you were using stringified keys, no, the appid wouldn't have changed, because the migration process would have no way of knowing they were keys. You should use a list of Key objects (Eg, `db.ListProperty(db.Key)`.

Comment: Oh right! Of course. I am indeed wondering why I didn't. I'll do the migration to HR, and then switch to `db.Key` lists. Thanks.